# Plotting a coloured 3D figure in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, scatter-plot

I have 3 axes: `X` of size N, `Y` of size M and `Z` of size O, which correspond to the coordinates of my data.

I have a matrix: `DATA` of size MxNxO, which corresponds to the module for each points.

I would like to plot the MATLAB figure of coordinate `X`, `Y`, `Z` and color the point depending of the value of the matrix `DATA` of size MxNxO.

I tried lots of functions such as `scatter3`, `surf`, `plot3`, but none is working as I wanted.

This is what I tried:

```matlab
n = 10;
x = linspace(0,10,n);
y = linspace(0,10,n);
z = linspace(0,10,n);

DATA = randn(n,n,n);

scatter3(x,y,z,DATA);
```

This code didn't work because `DATA` is not the same size as `x`, `y`, `z`. I also tried with:

```matlab
[X,Y,Z] = ndgrid(x,y,z) 
scatter3(X,Y,Z,DATA);
```

but this didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick with [`scatter3()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html#btr5_il-1) is to "unroll" your matrices to a column vector, and don't forget that the fourth argument is size, rather than colour:

```matlab
n = 10;
x = linspace(0,10,n);
y = linspace(0,10,n);
z = linspace(0,10,n);
[X,Y,Z] = ndgrid(x,y,z);
DATA = randn(n,n,n);

% here 3 is the size. You can set it to a different constant, or vary it as well
scatter3(X(:), Y(:), Z(:), 3, DATA(:));
```

Results in

[image]

You can colour a surface, see its [documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html#bvidelb-1), however, it doesn't seem to make much sense in your case, given you have a full cube of data points. A surface is 2D, whereas your data is 3D. For a 2D surface, simply follow the example in the docs:

```matlab
n = 10;
x = linspace(0,10,n);
y = linspace(0,10,n);

Z = rand(n);
DATA = randn(n);

surf(x, y, Z, DATA);
```

[image]

<sub>Images rendered in R2007b, syntax cross-checked with the documentation.</sub>

If you've got a surface defined by an M *-by-* 4 array containing X, Y, Z and Data, you can use [`delaunay()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunay.html) to create a Delaunay triangulation of your points and then [`trisurf()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trisurf.html) to plot that. Note that this still requires a 2D surface, albeit it can vary in three dimensions. The cube of data in your example still doesn't make sense to plot as a surface, even with this method.

Comment: You're right, a surface is not the best way to represent this type of _volumetric_ data (a scalar quantity defined in a 3D space. To show all the values available the 3D scatter plot, color coded, as in the first example is the way to go, but it can be very cluttered and difficult to read. Other options are to show one or more [`slice`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/slice.html) (you might have to reinterpolate your 3D domain for it to be smooth), or a potential good use of surface for volumetric data are [`isosurface`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isosurface.html)